# Exception Handling in Model Component

Tags: java, jsp

I am confused with the following question:

You are implementing a model component. You realize that an IOException might arise if you lose connection to the database. Following are the option:

1. Implement multipathing to provide redundant connectivity to the database, thereby avoiding that risk of connection failure.
2. Provide an error handler page, and use the page directive in the invoking ISP to redirect to that page if the error arises.
3. Use the JSTL  tag to take control if the exception arises.
4. Surround the problem area with a try/catch block and implement appropriate recovery or fallback behavior.

I think answer is option no 4 but it's written answer is 3 i don't know how?

Comment: Alternative 1) is not really a solution. It might reduce the risk of error, but they still need to be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the assumption is once an IOException is thrown, there is no way to reconnect to the database, hence you are left with JSTL, the view component, to display the appropriate error message.

Comment: that is good explanation. i was confused as db connectivity code is in class file so, we can do a try/catch there.